# Gitignore pattern to remove image transforms

Tags: image-transforms, git

Not sure on the gitignore pattern I need to add to ignore craft's image transforms it automatically generates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those image transform folders all start with an underscore. The following pattern should work, if you don't set up underscore folders yourself:

`public/assets/**/[_]*/`

Comment: I was having problems getting this to work down through all my subdirectories, so I put a .gitignore file in each of my image directories that ignore transforms directories I wanted to ignore. I used this pattern: /[_]*/